# 'ProcessName' Undeclared Identifier in urlmon.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Working with Git and have just pulled in a colleague's changes which have caused my local build to fail with errors coming from the windows kits includes. The solution builds on the build server and my colleague's development machine.

Googling these errors don't seem to bring any results so I thought I would check here.

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\objidlbase.h(296): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\objidlbase.h(296): error C2513: 'IAsyncManager': no variable declared before '='
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\objidlbase.h(5394): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\cguid.h(47): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\cguid.h(49): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\cguid.h(57): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\cguid.h(63): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(310): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(310): error C2513: 'IInternetSecurityManager': no variable declared before '='
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(345): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(345): error C2513: 'IInternetHostSecurityManager': no variable declared before '='
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(352): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(352): error C2513: 'IInternetZoneManager': no variable declared before '='
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(493): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(494): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(6864): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(6865): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(7071): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(8033): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(8447): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(8447): error C2513: 'IInternetZoneManager *': no variable declared before '='
>
> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um\urlmon.h(8571): error C2065: 'ProcessName': undeclared identifier

Comment: Have you installed the WDK ?

Comment: We are using VS2017 and this isn't listed in the installer package. What do we need? We have installed all of the windows SDKs.

Comment: Please post errors and the like as text, *not* as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's a problem with the Windows 10.0.14393.0 SDK, as Visual Studio is finding the headers, but not the libraries.

Try uninstalling and reinstalling this SDK (you may have to do this via Programs and Features rather than the Visual Studio installer).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I originally removed it via the Visual Studio Installer but that didn't work. Uninstalling from Programs and Features did the trick. Not sure how the SDK got corrupted in the first place.